# Кто знаком с ncruses на Си. Как там включить поддержку русского языка?

Tags: c, ncurses

Кто знаком с ncurses. Почему русские символы на linux отображаются так :
[image: Вот линукс]

А на маке отображаются корректно : [image: Вот как на маке]

Comment: судя по маку текст у вас правильный, видимо в UTF-8, гуглите по словам UFT-8 ncurses

Answer (score 2):

В linux нужно вызвать [setlocale(LC_ALL, "")](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setlocale) в первых строках программы.

(пример взят [отсюда](https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/development/3462740))

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <locale.h>

void sig(int n)
{
}

int main()
{
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  signal(SIGINT, sig);

  initscr();
  char text[]="Русский UTF-8 текст\n";
  printw("%s",text);
  refresh();
  pause();
  endwin();

  return 0;
}
```

При компиляции не забудьте указать библиотеку

```
gcc txx.c -lncursesw
```

Для завершения программы нажмите `Ctrl-C`

Comment: А не подскажете, то что текст выходит за границы рамки это никак не исправить в ncurses? Или можно исправить только с помощью mvwprintw? Просто у меня это выводится автоматически из другой функции(пытаюсь интегрировать код в меню), и там постоянно ломается рамки при выводе или вводе текста

Comment: К сожалению, не знаю, реальных программ с curses я не писал.  Попробуйте задать отдельным вопросом, может кто-то пишущий на curses его увидит. Кстати, рамки ломаются только с русским языком или с ascii тоже? Наверное этот момент стоит написать в вопросе.

Comment: Рамки ломаются в любом случае. Возможно это баг с самим ncurses, возможно я чего то не знаю) Но вопрос, на который вы ответили, мне помог, благодарю

Comment: *`"Рамки ломаются в любом случае"`* -- imho это хорошо, скорее всего баг не в curses, найти и исправить будет проще